# Cannot access visualsvn remotely

Tags: apache, svn, visualsvn-server

I've installed VisualSVN and configured it's network settings so it should work remotely but it works only locally. I have a list of available IPs at **VisualSVN Server > Properties > Network**. There under "**These IP addresses:**" If I choose an IP like 192.168... (from the suggested list) and set it as **server name** - I can access the svn repository, but I can't access this repository from the different PC which is not in local area network.

I found out via http://www.whatsmyip.org/ that my IP is different - it starts from 82.117.... So the point is that my external IP address differs from the list of suggested by VisualSVN IPs. Could be the problem in the router? When I'm trying to set this external IP I'm getting an error - "**VisualSVN Server service failed to restart**" In the eventlog I found - "**make_sock: could not bind to address 82.117...:8080
(OS 10049) The requested address is not valid in its context.** " , then "**no listening sockets available, shutting down**" and "**Unable to open logs**".

What should I do to be able to connect to svn repository from any PC if I provide it my credentials. My VisualSVN version is *Standard*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP 82.117.x.x belongs to the network router, not your machine. Your machine has only LAN IP which starts with 192.168. You are required to setup port-forwarding on your router to forward all request on specific port (e.g. 8080) to your machine. As well, make sure that you have static IP or setup some dynamic DNS service.

Generally speaking, you are required to perform the same steps as for configuring any web server to be available from WAN.

Comment: Do I need to configure Apache?

Comment: @ИгорьЛозовский you don't need to configure it manually except the IP interface and port number which you can adjust in VisualSVN Server Manager console. Most of the configuration should be done on the side of your router and ISP.\